# Correctly add a legend to a seaborn jointplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have two distributions plotting in a seaborn jointplot like so:

```
graph = sns.jointplot(setosa.sepal_width, setosa.sepal_length,
                 cmap="Reds", kind="kde", marginal_kws={"color":"r", "alpha":.2}, shade=True, shade_lowest=False, alpha=.5)

graph.x = virginica.sepal_width
graph.y = virginica.sepal_length
graph.plot_joint(sns.kdeplot, cmap="Blues", shade=True, shade_lowest=False, alpha=.5)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.legend(["setosa", "virginica"])
graph.plot_marginals(sns.kdeplot, color='b', shade=True, alpha=.2, legend=False)
```

[image: Output Image]

Notice on the legend, that the `setosa` and `virginica` have no color to their left. Is there any way to correctly add a legend to a jointplot in seaborn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `label` to both of your plotting calls, and remove the names from `ax.legend()`.  So the full example (see the `#CHANGE HERE` comments):

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#I'm taking a stab at defining what you had
#the resulting plot is different
#but method still applies
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
setosa = iris[iris['species'] == 'setosa']
virginica = iris[iris['species'] == 'virginica']

graph = sns.jointplot(setosa.sepal_width, setosa.sepal_length,
                 cmap="Reds", kind="kde", marginal_kws={"color":"r", "alpha":.2}, shade=True, shade_lowest=False, alpha=.5,
                 label='setosa')      ## CHANGE HERE

graph.x = virginica.sepal_width
graph.y = virginica.sepal_length
graph.plot_joint(sns.kdeplot, cmap="Blues", shade=True, shade_lowest=False, alpha=.5, label='virginica')   ## CHANGE HERE
graph.set_axis_labels()
ax = plt.gca()
ax.legend()  #CHANGE HERE
graph.plot_marginals(sns.kdeplot, color='b', shade=True, alpha=.2, legend=False)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Plot is different because I accidentally labelled `virginica` as `setosa`. This is exactly what I was looking for though!